# Accessibility inspector does not recognize uitextview in iOS 9 simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, ios9, inspector

I need to see accessibility labels on an application for testing purposes. I want to see its accessiblity label when i tap on an uitextview, and it works pretty good on iOS8.4 simulator. However not working at all in iOS9 simulator. Can this be an issue with iOS9.0? or is it something related to uitextview?

By the way, i already set uitextview's accessibility label.

**in iOS8.4 simulator when i tap on textView**

[image: iOS8.4] [image: iOS8.4]

**in iOS9.0 simulator when i tap on textView**

[image: iOS9.0] [image: iOS9.0]